# How to get the list of possible placements for a set of keywords using Google Adwords API?

Tags: java, google-ads-api

I want to get the list of all possible placement ideas for a particular set of keywords. I came across [Google Display Planner](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/3056153?hl=en) which gives you placement ideas. I did not get any API for Google Display Planner. Also, I stumbled upon [this](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-adwords-java/source/browse/trunk/examples/v201302/GetRelatedPlacements.java?r=276). But it takes url as an input and gives related website. Is there any way I can do this in JAVA using Google Adwords API or without them?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you just need to use the [TargetingIdeaService](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201406/TargetingIdeaService#getBulkKeywordIdeas) and the getBulkKeywordIdeas method.

When you make the request, you can pass in a TargetingIdeaSelector object with the IdeaType set to PLACEMENT to get placement ideas instead of keywords.  I've not done or tried this myself but it sounds like exactly what you need?